# Retrofit2 ApiServices savepoint showing null object reference

Tags: retrofit

DetailFragment.java

```
 public void sendPost() {
    mAPIService.savePost("O3", 2, "ssfu", "jhsgdhf", 20, "mystring", 1, "UnoiaTech", "hdbjhsdhfjsd").enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Submited" + response.body(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i(TAG, "post submitted to API." + response.body().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error To Post API in DetailFragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to submit post to API.");
        }
    });
}
```

PlanFragment.java

```
next_plan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    detailFragment.sendPost();

}
```

});

ApiUtils.java

```
public class ApiUtils {

private ApiUtils() {}

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.100.14:8080";

public static APIService getAPIService() {

    return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(APIService.class);
}
```

}

RetroClient.java

```
public class RetrofitClient {
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

ApiService.java

```
public interface APIService {

@POST("/deals/deal")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Post> savePost(@Field("bookingType") String bookingType,
                    @Field("dealPrice") int dealPrice,
                    @Field("description") String  description,
                     @Field("keyword") String keyword,
                    @Field("originalPrice") int originalPrice,
                    @Field("plan") String plan,
                    @Field("shopId") int shopId,
                    @Field("shopName") String shopName,
                    @Field("title") String title);
```

}

Showing error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: googlemap.arun.com.mywork2, PID: 20969
>                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'retrofit2.Call
>   googlemap.arun.com.mywork2.data.remote.APIService.savePost(java.lang.String,
>   int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, int,
>   java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                   at
>   googlemap.arun.com.mywork2.DetailFragment.sendPost(DetailFragment.java:104)
>                                                                                   at
>   googlemap.arun.com.mywork2.PlanFragment$5.onClick(PlanFragment.java:85)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5272)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21528)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5857)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:887)

Comment: APIService is null

Comment: so how can i resolve it

Comment: How are you initializing `mApiServices` in `DetailFragment`?

Comment: here is     mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();